# Why `'' in 'foo'` returns True in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following took me by suprise:

```py
>> '' in 'foo'  
True # huh?!
```

but

```py
>> 'b' in 'foo' 
False # as expected
```

I would assume that an empty string is not a substring of anything so it would return false, but that is not the case. What do I miss here?

Comment: If you add `''` to a string (`a = 'hello'; a += ''`), your result is the same. It's a bit like `1` being a common factor to any `int`

Comment: so an 'empty string' is always part of a string?

Comment: Yes, even an empty string. `'' in ''` => `True`

Comment: @C.Nivs if you could asnwer my question i would accept it :)

Comment: I cannot, it's been marked as a duplicate, but I'm glad you found it helpful